# Symfony 2.8.8 dump function php7.1 not working

Tags: php, symfony, php-7, symfony-2.8

Recently I've upgraded my php to 7.1 and symfony to 2.8 and everything works ok but dump function, when I try to use it I get:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered
>   500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException
>
> in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Cloner/VarCloner.php at line 298   -
>               }
>           }
>           self::$hashMask ^= hexdec(substr(spl_object_hash($obj), self::$hashOffset, PHP_INT_SIZE));
>       }
>   }

I do not know if it's something related to php configuration or what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE** it seems to be fixed on Symfony 2.8.10.

---

*Previous answer*:
Well, I have found a non pretty nice answer, but it works, so what I've done is copying the class `VarCloner.php` from Symfony 3.1.3 and changing it on my symfony 2.8, and that worked! So [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.1/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Cloner/VarCloner.php) is the class, I also paste here the one that I tried.

```
<?php 
/*
* This file is part of the Symfony package.
*
* (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
*
* For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
* file that was distributed with this source code.
*/ 

namespace Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner;

/**
* @author Nicolas Grekas <p@tchwork.com>
*/
class VarCloner extends AbstractCloner
{
private static $hashMask = 0;
private static $hashOffset = 0;

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function doClone($var)
{
    $useExt = $this->useExt;
    $i = 0;                         // Current iteration position in $queue
    $len = 1;                       // Length of $queue
    $pos = 0;                       // Number of cloned items past the first level
    $refsCounter = 0;               // Hard references counter
    $queue = array(array($var));    // This breadth-first queue is the return value
    $arrayRefs = array();           // Map of queue indexes to stub array objects
    $hardRefs = array();            // Map of original zval hashes to stub objects
    $objRefs = array();             // Map of original object handles to their stub object couterpart
    $resRefs = array();             // Map of original resource handles to their stub object couterpart
    $values = array();              // Map of stub objects' hashes to original values
    $maxItems = $this->maxItems;
    $maxString = $this->maxString;
    $cookie = (object) array();     // Unique object used to detect hard references
    $gid = uniqid(mt_rand(), true); // Unique string used to detect the special $GLOBALS variable
    $a = null;                      // Array cast for nested structures
    $stub = null;                   // Stub capturing the main properties of an original item value
                                    // or null if the original value is used directly
    $zval = array(                  // Main properties of the current value
        'type' => null,
        'zval_isref' => null,
        'zval_hash' => null,
        'array_count' => null,
        'object_class' => null,
        'object_handle' => null,
        'resource_type' => null,
    );
    if (!self::$hashMask) {
        self::initHashMask();
    }
    $hashMask = self::$hashMask;
    $hashOffset = self::$hashOffset;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
        $indexed = true;            // Whether the currently iterated array is numerically indexed or not
        $j = -1;                    // Position in the currently iterated array
        $fromObjCast = array_keys($queue[$i]);
        $fromObjCast = array_keys(array_flip($fromObjCast)) !== $fromObjCast;
        $refs = $vals = $fromObjCast ? array_values($queue[$i]) : $queue[$i];
        foreach ($queue[$i] as $k => $v) {
            // $k is the original key
            // $v is the original value or a stub object in case of hard references
            if ($k !== ++$j) {
                $indexed = false;
            }
            if ($fromObjCast) {
                $k = $j;
            }
            if ($useExt) {
                $zval = symfony_zval_info($k, $refs);
            } else {
                $refs[$k] = $cookie;
                if ($zval['zval_isref'] = $vals[$k] === $cookie) {
                    $zval['zval_hash'] = $v instanceof Stub ? spl_object_hash($v) : null;
                }
                $zval['type'] = gettype($v);
            }
            if ($zval['zval_isref']) {
                $vals[$k] = &$stub;         // Break hard references to make $queue completely
                unset($stub);               // independent from the original structure
                if (isset($hardRefs[$zval['zval_hash']])) {
                    $vals[$k] = $useExt ? ($v = $hardRefs[$zval['zval_hash']]) : ($refs[$k] = $v);
                    if ($v->value instanceof Stub && (Stub::TYPE_OBJECT === $v->value->type || Stub::TYPE_RESOURCE === $v->value->type)) {
                        ++$v->value->refCount;
                    }
                    ++$v->refCount;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            // Create $stub when the original value $v can not be used directly
            // If $v is a nested structure, put that structure in array $a
            switch ($zval['type']) {
                case 'string':
                    if (isset($v[0]) && !preg_match('//u', $v)) {
                        $stub = new Stub();
                        $stub->type = Stub::TYPE_STRING;
                        $stub->class = Stub::STRING_BINARY;
                        if (0 <= $maxString && 0 < $cut = strlen($v) - $maxString) {
                            $stub->cut = $cut;
                            $stub->value = substr($v, 0, -$cut);
                        } else {
                            $stub->value = $v;
                        }
                    } elseif (0 <= $maxString && isset($v[1 + ($maxString >> 2)]) && 0 < $cut = mb_strlen($v, 'UTF-8') - $maxString) {
                        $stub = new Stub();
                        $stub->type = Stub::TYPE_STRING;
                        $stub->class = Stub::STRING_UTF8;
                        $stub->cut = $cut;
                        $stub->value = mb_substr($v, 0, $maxString, 'UTF-8');
                    }
                    break;

                case 'integer':
                    break;

                case 'array':
                    if ($v) {
                        $stub = $arrayRefs[$len] = new Stub();
                        $stub->type = Stub::TYPE_ARRAY;
                        $stub->class = Stub::ARRAY_ASSOC;

                        // Copies of $GLOBALS have very strange behavior,
                        // let's detect them with some black magic
                        $a = $v;
                        $a[$gid] = true;

                        // Happens with copies of $GLOBALS
                        if (isset($v[$gid])) {
                            unset($v[$gid]);
                            $a = array();
                            foreach ($v as $gk => &$gv) {
                                $a[$gk] = &$gv;
                            }
                        } else {
                            $a = $v;
                        }

                        $stub->value = $zval['array_count'] ?: count($a);
                    }
                    break;

                case 'object':
                    if (empty($objRefs[$h = $zval['object_handle'] ?: ($hashMask ^ hexdec(substr(spl_object_hash($v), $hashOffset, PHP_INT_SIZE)))])) {
                        $stub = new Stub();
                        $stub->type = Stub::TYPE_OBJECT;
                        $stub->class = $zval['object_class'] ?: get_class($v);
                        $stub->value = $v;
                        $stub->handle = $h;
                        $a = $this->castObject($stub, 0 < $i);
                        if ($v !== $stub->value) {
                            if (Stub::TYPE_OBJECT !== $stub->type || null === $stub->value) {
                                break;
                            }
                            if ($useExt) {
                                $zval['type'] = $stub->value;
                                $zval = symfony_zval_info('type', $zval);
                                $h = $zval['object_handle'];
                            } else {
                                $h = $hashMask ^ hexdec(substr(spl_object_hash($stub->value), $hashOffset, PHP_INT_SIZE));
                            }
                            $stub->handle = $h;
                        }
                        $stub->value = null;
                        if (0 <= $maxItems && $maxItems <= $pos) {
                            $stub->cut = count($a);
                            $a = null;
                        }
                    }
                    if (empty($objRefs[$h])) {
                        $objRefs[$h] = $stub;
                    } else {
                        $stub = $objRefs[$h];
                        ++$stub->refCount;
                        $a = null;
                    }
                    break;

                case 'resource':
                case 'unknown type':
                    if (empty($resRefs[$h = (int) $v])) {
                        $stub = new Stub();
                        $stub->type = Stub::TYPE_RESOURCE;
                        $stub->class = $zval['resource_type'] ?: get_resource_type($v);
                        $stub->value = $v;
                        $stub->handle = $h;
                        $a = $this->castResource($stub, 0 < $i);
                        $stub->value = null;
                        if (0 <= $maxItems && $maxItems <= $pos) {
                            $stub->cut = count($a);
                            $a = null;
                        }
                    }
                    if (empty($resRefs[$h])) {
                        $resRefs[$h] = $stub;
                    } else {
                        $stub = $resRefs[$h];
                        ++$stub->refCount;
                        $a = null;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            if (isset($stub)) {
                if ($zval['zval_isref']) {
                    if ($useExt) {
                        $vals[$k] = $hardRefs[$zval['zval_hash']] = $v = new Stub();
                        $v->value = $stub;
                    } else {
                        $refs[$k] = new Stub();
                        $refs[$k]->value = $stub;
                        $h = spl_object_hash($refs[$k]);
                        $vals[$k] = $hardRefs[$h] = &$refs[$k];
                        $values[$h] = $v;
                    }
                    $vals[$k]->handle = ++$refsCounter;
                } else {
                    $vals[$k] = $stub;
                }

                if ($a) {
                    if ($i && 0 <= $maxItems) {
                        $k = count($a);
                        if ($pos < $maxItems) {
                            if ($maxItems < $pos += $k) {
                                $a = array_slice($a, 0, $maxItems - $pos);
                                if ($stub->cut >= 0) {
                                    $stub->cut += $pos - $maxItems;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            if ($stub->cut >= 0) {
                                $stub->cut += $k;
                            }
                            $stub = $a = null;
                            unset($arrayRefs[$len]);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    $queue[$len] = $a;
                    $stub->position = $len++;
                }
                $stub = $a = null;
            } elseif ($zval['zval_isref']) {
                if ($useExt) {
                    $vals[$k] = $hardRefs[$zval['zval_hash']] = new Stub();
                    $vals[$k]->value = $v;
                } else {
                    $refs[$k] = $vals[$k] = new Stub();
                    $refs[$k]->value = $v;
                    $h = spl_object_hash($refs[$k]);
                    $hardRefs[$h] = &$refs[$k];
                    $values[$h] = $v;
                }
                $vals[$k]->handle = ++$refsCounter;
            }
        }

        if ($fromObjCast) {
            $refs = $vals;
            $vals = array();
            $j = -1;
            foreach ($queue[$i] as $k => $v) {
                foreach (array($k => $v) as $a => $v) {
                }
                if ($a !== $k) {
                    $vals = (object) $vals;
                    $vals->{$k} = $refs[++$j];
                    $vals = (array) $vals;
                } else {
                    $vals[$k] = $refs[++$j];
                }
            }
        }

        $queue[$i] = $vals;

        if (isset($arrayRefs[$i])) {
            if ($indexed) {
                $arrayRefs[$i]->class = Stub::ARRAY_INDEXED;
            }
            unset($arrayRefs[$i]);
        }
    }

    foreach ($values as $h => $v) {
        $hardRefs[$h] = $v;
    }

    return $queue;
}

private static function initHashMask()
{
    $obj = (object) array();
    self::$hashOffset = 16 - PHP_INT_SIZE;
    self::$hashMask = -1;

    if (defined('HHVM_VERSION')) {
        self::$hashOffset += 16;
    } else {
        // check if we are nested in an output buffering handler to prevent a fatal error with ob_start() below
        $obFuncs = array('ob_clean', 'ob_end_clean', 'ob_flush', 'ob_end_flush', 'ob_get_contents', 'ob_get_flush');
        foreach (debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS) as $frame) {
            if (isset($frame['function'][0]) && !isset($frame['class']) && 'o' === $frame['function'][0] && in_array($frame['function'], $obFuncs)) {
                $frame['line'] = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($frame['line'])) {
            ob_start();
            debug_zval_dump($obj);
            self::$hashMask = (int) substr(ob_get_clean(), 17);
        }
    }

    self::$hashMask ^= hexdec(substr(spl_object_hash($obj), self::$hashOffset, PHP_INT_SIZE));
}
}
```

paste it into `YourProject/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Cloner/VarCloner.php`

so, if someone find a better option, please give it to us! Thanks!!